# Actionbar on top of PhoneGap webview

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm trying to add the actionbar of Android(4.0) to the webview activity of PhoneGap (2.0.0). I'm using the same actionbar in another activity in my application. It's in the menu.xml file and in the other activity everything is working without any problem.

When I load the webview, the actionbar is not shown. 
I get a nullPointerExeption on the actionbar. I already have the @targetApi(14). And the resource is working for the homeactivity but not for the webviewactivity.

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bar));
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```

I found getActionBar is a function from the Activity class and this is returning null. Probably phonegap is giving a twist to the activty and therefore it is not possible to load the actionbar.

Anybody experience with this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true);
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

The setBooleanProperty before super.onCreate was the answer for the problem